# Subnormal subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for non-abelian groups whose all subnormal subgroups are cyclic.

I found an example, that Quasi simple group with cyclic center, have all subnormal subgroups are cyclic.

Does there exists, any other Group whose all subnormal subgroups are cyclic ?

Comment: Probably not what you want, but cyclic groups work.

Comment: The group is subnormal in itself, so I assume you want to leave that out.

Answer (score 0):

Every subgroup of a nilpotent group is subnormal.  The Klein 4-group is nilpotent and has only cyclic (proper) subgroups.  So example(s) exists.

Regarding your (new) requirement for nonabelian groups:  The quaternion group is nonabelian, nilpotent, and all its (proper) subgroups are cyclic.

Comment: $S_3$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Right.  Center is trivial.  (It's too early here.)

Comment: @Amin : Might want to add that to your question.